# Advanced site search with google

Tags: url

I try to find out which URLs exists for a specific domain and a specific domain-path in the google index. The urls have the following schema:

```
https://example.org/path1/<keyword>/path2/
```

the following google search works fine:

```
site:https://example.org/path1/*/path2/
```

but it delivers more than 40.000 findings. So I'll try to search for

```
https://example.org/path1/a*/path2/
```

but there where no results found (what can't be). Whats wrong? Any chance to deliver only Findings where Site-URL contains keywords starting with an "a"?

Thank you,
Jan

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following

```
https://example.org/path1/*a
```

This will search for all the URL's which starts with `https://example.org/path1/` which also contains the keyword `a`

You can refine your search by specifying multiple keywords:

```
https://example.org/path1/*a*/path2/
```

This will search for the same as in the 1st example but will conatin the `/path2/` part of the URL as well. However this will match URL's if the keyword `a` is either before or after the 2nd path `/path2/`